# Regex - Pull all strings, but with spaces if in between quotes (Preferably without quotes)

Tags: regex, quotes

All, I am trying pull a collection/array of strings. I have found Regex would probably be the best way to do this.

I have a string formatted as such with slight variations

```
string1 "string 2" "string.3" string4 string5
```

I want to output everything as such

```
output 1 = string1
output 2 = string 2 //without quotes preferably
output 3 = string.3 //without quotes preferably
output 4 = string4
output 5 = string5
```

I really just need the Regex portion.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are going to process it, and in what language, this is might get what you want (it works for javascript, C#):

`[^ "][^ ]*|"([^"]*)"`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in browser console JavaScript regex

**(\w+[\s\d.]+)**

```
'string1 "string 2" "string.3" string4 string5'.match(/(\w+[\s\d.]+)/gi)

// output is
["string1 ", "string 2", "string.3", "string4 ", "string5"]
```